# using grep and wc commands to solve a problem

Tags: files, grep, wc

I am trying to figure out how to count the number of lines in `file.txt` that have at least ONE number or digit.

So far I figure will count the amount of lines:

```
wc -l filename.txt
```

I then figure this `grep` command will display all lines in `file.txt` that contain at least one digit:

```
grep -E '[0-9]+' list.txt
```

How do I combine the them to find the answer to my question?

Answer (score 5):

try

```
grep -c -E '[0-9]+' list.txt
```

where

- -c stand for count

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -c \[0-9] <infile
```

...that should be all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
grep -rlZ '[0-9]' . | xargs -0 wc -l
```

- `grep` with `-r` will search trough all files in the current directory recursively

  - `-l` prints only file with at least one match
  - `-Z` prints those filename delimited by nullbyte to cope with special filenames
  - `'[0-9]'` searches the files for digits
- `xargs -0` reads the list of the files (from `grep` produced) delimited by the nullbyte

  - `wc -l` and calls `wc -l` on them to count the lines.

---

Example output:

```
 3 ./file1
 6 ./dir/file2
 9 total
```